# Error en la conexión de hibernate reverse engineering

Tags: java, hibernate

que tal, estoy haciendo una pequeña practica de Java con Hibernate, pero al momento de crear el archivo "Hibernate Reverse Engineering Wizard" me pone el siguiente mensaje de error:
[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4g94D.png]

Ya he investigado y borrado y rehacer la conexión a la base de datos SQLServer, verificar que la conexión apunte a la tabla que quiero, pero me sigue apareciendo ese error.